# How to filter a data frame from each first non NaN value until next and sum values from corresponding column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am struggling with the following data frame:

```
Activity        Duration (mins)
BREAK/REST      120
AVAILABILITY    57
WORK            13
DRIVING         10
WORK            31
DRIVING         100
DRIVING         81
DRIVING         106
BREAK/REST      89
BREAK/REST      4
```

I am trying to find total duration for similar consecutive activities. Following is the output I am trying to achieve.

```
Activity        Duration (mins)
BREAK/REST      120
AVAILABILITY    57
WORK            13
DRIVING         10
WORK            31
DRIVING         287
BREAK/REST      93
```

I am doing something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('reformed_data.xlsx')
df['Activity'].mask((df['Activity'].shift()==df['Activity']), inplace=True)
```

I am stuck at this point and don't know how to proceed. Please help! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC we need `shift` + `cumsum` create the group key

```
s=df.groupby(df.Activity.ne(df.Activity.shift()).cumsum()).\
    agg({'Activity':'first','Duration(mins)':'sum'})
s
Out[185]: 
              Activity  Duration(mins)
Activity                              
1           BREAK/REST             120
2         AVAILABILITY              57
3                 WORK              13
4              DRIVING              10
5                 WORK              31
6              DRIVING             287
7           BREAK/REST              93
```

Comment: can you please tell how to keep all the columns if there is any other than those 'Activity' and 'Duration (mins)'? Thanks

Comment: @UmarAftab you can do agg({'Activity':'first','Duration(mins)':'sum','Other':'first'})